# PowerBuilder - SCAUTIL.DLL function ENC()

Tags: encryption, dll, powerbuilder

In PowerBuilder 9.0 I have:
FUNCTION long Enc (string pwd) LIBRARY "SCAUTIL.DLL";

The ENC function is an external function. Does anyone know what algorithm to use?

Example:
The 'password' string after encrypting is '222298'.

Comment: You'd need to find the API documentation for your encryption / decryption routines. The question isn't specific to PowerBuilder so that tag probably not appropriate even though you happen to be calling it from PB.

Answer (score 0):

You have to contact the people who made SCAUTIL.DLL it doesn't look like a public DLL (no hits in Google) so probably something made in-house.